# TFS Update 3 missing CI Path Filters

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

We have TFS 2015 Update 3 installed locally hosting Git repositories.  We're trying to exclude certain paths from triggering CI builds, and all the documentation says there should be "Path Filters", but we only see Branch Filters.

Any suggestions on how to make the Path Filters accessible?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked TFS 2015.3, there is no Path Filters available. But [this feature](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#git-filters) has already existed in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service) and TFS 15.

I have submit a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it, Product Team will evaluate this seriously:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16246687-tfs-2015-update-3-doesn-t-have-ci-path-filters