# trigger a build on check in specific folder in git repository in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 as a build server and bitbucket as the source repository. I am trying to implement build trigger on check-in in a specific folder

Like: I have following directory structure in master:

master/driver

master/SRC

I want to have two build configuration for the same branch master ( for driver and other for Product). Each configuration should trigger a build on check in their specific folder.

FYI: Path filters are not  available in my TFS 2015

Can set filters on branch only

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Update 3 missing CI Path Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538566/tfs-update-3-missing-ci-path-filters)

Comment: Hi codinggrapes, any update for this issue? Daniel is right,it's a known issue for TFS2015 update3.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not available on TFS2015 update3. You could take a look at below similar question:

- [git filter in on premise TFS 2015 Update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082081/git-filter-in-on-premise-tfs-2015-update-3)
- [TFS Update 3 missing CI Path Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538566/tfs-update-3-missing-ci-path-filters)

More detail info about path filter you could refer this blog: [Path Filters in VSTS Build](http://mitchdenny.com/path-filters-in-vsts-build/). To use this feature you should either update TFS to TFS2017 or use visual studio team services.